# Return unique objects with unique value and key pair from REST API call?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

[Console log Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRvta.png) The bottom array contains multiple objects returned from REST API call of SharePoint list.

var items = data.d.results[i];

console.log(items);

object

object

object

On the above instance 3 objects are returned from rest call, and two of the objects have similar key for the same value for ticket

object

```
 ticket : 1234
 size : 3
```

object

```
  ticket : 4567
  size : 5
```

object

```
  ticket : 1234
  size : 8
```

What I am looking is to **return only the 2 objects** from  var items = data.d.results[i];  array with unique key value pair like the bottom, order doesn’t matter. JavaScript or JQuery works.

object

```
    ticket : 1234
    size : 3
```

object

```
    ticket : 4567
    size : 5


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getListItems, "sp.js");
    });
    function getListItems() {     
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/Items?$Select=Title,ticket",
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            });

       function onSuccess(data){
        for(var i=0; i<data.d.results.length; i++){
          var items = data.d.results[i];
          console.log(items);
          }
         }
        };

</script>
```

filter the objects based on ticket column that are only unique and return all metadata of each list items(objects)

Comment: Please check the solution posted and let me know if that works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
 var results=[
  {
     ticket : 1234,
     size : 3
  },{
     ticket : 3434,
     size : 2
  },{
     ticket : 1234,
     size : 9
  },{
     ticket : 1234,
     size : 93
  }
];  
const filterResults=(results)=>{
  const flags=[],output=[];
  results.forEach((result)=>{
    if(flags.indexOf(result.ticket)<0){
      output.push(result)
      flags.push(result.ticket)
    }
  })
  return output;
}
console.log(filterResults(results))
```

Comment: I am getting Uncaught TypeError:Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined, to make it clear, var items = data.d.results[i]; on console log print return the object as these https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRvta.png

Comment: How did you try to run this ?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass the results array into the `filterResults` method, like `filterResults(data.d.results)` and remove that loop, which is already done in the `filterResults` Function

Answer (score 0):

If possible you should consider doing this on backend. What will you do if you have another client? Programming the same logic again?

Comment: doesn't have backend access,it is for intera net only

Answer (score 0):

Could get the unique value for ticket column like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getListItems(url, listname, query, complete, failure) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                complete(data.d.results); 
            },
            error: function (data) {
                failure(data);
            }
        });
    }


    getListItems('http://sp','UniqueValue','?$select=ticket',

     function(items){    
         console.log(items)

         var UniqueTickets = groupBy(items,'ticket');
          //This gives unique value array
           console.log(UniqueTickets)


        },


        function(error){
           console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }


    );

    function groupBy(items,propertyName)
    {
        var result = [];
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
           if ($.inArray(item[propertyName], result)==-1) {
              result.push(item[propertyName]);
           }
        });
        return result;
    }
    </script>
```

This is the full data.d.results array:

[image]

This is the unique ticket array after converting:

[image]

Comment: it looks like your code only return the filtered ticket number, I am looking for filter the same way but return the objects with all metadata

Comment: @SokeTelesh, you could pass column name into GroupBy function, for other metadata column.